# Regex in PHP to extract data from website

Tags: php, regex, data-extraction

I am new to php. As a part of my course homework assignment , I am required to extract data from a website and using that data render a table.

P.S. : Using regex is not a good option but we are not allowed to use any library like DOM, jQuery etc.

Char set is UTF-8.

```
$searchURL = "http://www.allmusic.com/search/artists/the+beatles";
$html = file_get_contents($searchURL);

$patternform = '/<form(.*)<\/form>/sm';
preg_match_all($patternform ,$html,$matches);
```

Here regex works fine but when I apply the same regex for table tag, it return me empty array. Is there something to do with whitespaces in $html ?

What is wrong here?

Comment: Why are you not allowed... homework?

Comment: You should read this [How to parse and process HTML/XML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/1592648) Any class telling you to use regex over DOM is a class you should un-enroll from and get a refund.

Comment: What information do you need? Target only the specific fields you need, build an array of objects, and then display them in a table. Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: We are not allowed  to use any external library because they want us to learn the hard way, loose our sleep, get cranky and then post questions on forums for HELP !!

Comment: @Margi PHP DOM is not an external library it is part of PHP, check out the above link.

Comment: @MathieuImbert : My regex for extracting table returns me am empty array. /<table(.*)<\/table>/sm

Comment: The Prof has mentioned in the homework specs to not to use DOM APIs.

Comment: You need the whole table? Then `'/(<table.*<\/table>)/sm'` works for me.

Comment: That might not work due to new lines, try /<table.*?>([^]*?)<\/table>/sm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code produces a good result:

```
$searchURL = "http://www.allmusic.com/search/artists/the+beatles";
$html = file_get_contents($searchURL);

$patternform = '/(<table.*<\/table>)/sm';
preg_match_all($patternform ,$html,$matches);

echo $matches[0][0];
```

Result:

[image]